# Position element relative to page instead of parent? HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

So--after a page with a large number of elements styled with similar classes was constructed-- the client decided he wanted things shifted around.  I'd prefer not to manually change every single HTML element, so is there a way to simply position them (via CSS) based on the overall page?

(something pure CSS, that is; of course, some javascript could accomplish it)

Comment: please provide any code at all.

Comment: it depends how the page is built, but you can place things relative to the body (the whole page) if you use absolute positioning, not inside a relative-positioned element, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867244/force-position-absolute-to-be-relative-to-document-not-parent-container

Comment: Unfortunately its ancestors are positioned.

Comment: I updated my answer below. You can still position the children using negative values (ie. top:-20px;). Warning: this method will get messy, and the code will become much less flexible.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a position:relative; on an ancestor tag, then use position:absolute; on anything you need to move around. You can use the top, right, bottom, left rules to position the item relative to the body tag.

```
ancestorSelector { position:relative; }
somethingToMoveSelector { position:absolute; top:100px; left:250px; }
```

[More on CSS positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)