# How to make absolutely positioned element take full screen width when it is inside fixed width container?

Tags: html, css

Html:

```
<div id='id1'>
  <div id='id2'>
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
#id1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}
#id2 {
  position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%; top: 20px; background: green; height: 30px;
}
```

I want #id2 to take full screen width. I can specify left: -Npx and right: -Npx, but this will work only for some screen sizes.

## id2 must not go beyond screen, so I can not specify left: -9999px;

Related fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aLubmd4a/

Comment: You would have to remove `position: relative` on the `#id1`, because that property is there for achieving the exact opposite of what you try. See [force “position: absolute” to be relative to document not parent container](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6867244/3162554).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#id2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: -100%;
    right: -100%;
    top: 20px;
    background: green;
    height: 30px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aLubmd4a/1/

Comment: Good to know this but it doesn't start from very beginning or end at the end, so `-100%` must be just random i guess? Does it mean anything?

Comment: @divy3993 It means 100% of the parent's width. This solution just gives the `#id2` a width of 900px...

Comment: Yes but does that have to do anything with screen or body's `width` or area? So how is this helpful? just asking.

Comment: @divy3993 No, it doesn't and it isn't helpful. I guess that's why someone downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

It is a partial solution, I've changed the `position` of the `#id2` element from `position:absolute;` to `position:fixed;`

Updated your fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/aLubmd4a/2/

If I understand you correctly, what you want to achieve is not really possible. An element's size AND positioning have to be in relation to some context.

In your example, you want it to take the width of the **body**, but be positioned (vertically) in relation to your `#id1` element, right? If so, you should pick a side, and either take the inner div (`#id2`) out of `#id1`, or make sure that you update the top/left of the inner `#id2` accordingly.