# Extend image to left such that it covers whole screen

Tags: css

Recently I have come across a problem for which I am not finding any appropriate solution.

Below is the image which gives an idea of what i am trying to achieve:

[image: what i am trying to achieve]

The div shown by the arrow is the mark of the problem which i am finding a solution for.
The problem is I want the div to be extended to full screen.
This div is inside a parent div who has a fixed width due to which i am not able to extend my image to full screen.

Have tried giving overflow to parent but isn't working.

I have tried below solution which is working to a certain extent but need a reliable solution.

```
width: 100%;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
margin-left: calc(-31.5vw);
align-content: center;
```

Could someone please provide some solution to this?

Comment: You need to remove all relative position from his parents and put left and righg to 0. For more info on positions have a look at this https://tutorialzine.com/2010/06/microtut-how-css-position-works

Answer (score 2):

```css
html, body
    {width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;}
    
    #parent{ 
        display: block;
        background-color: yellow;
        border: 1px solid red;
        position: fixed; 
        width: 200px; 
         height:100%;
    }
    #child1{ 
        background-color: red; 
         display: block;
      border: 1px solid yellow; 
        position: absolute; 
      width: 100vw;
  margin-left: calc(200px - 100%);
  //top:0px
    }
```

```html
<div id="parent">parent with position: fixed 
    <div id="child1">child wrapper (uncomment top to fit the parent wrapper)</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Ramin.
Just wanted to know what margin-left:calc does..The solution which you have provided works for all screen resolutions or is particular for some screens only?
And if it's not dynamic how can we get it done so that it matches each screen resolutions?

Comment: Hi,
yes it does work for every screen size. run the code snippet and resize your window, simple as that.  I just corrected my code.  margin-left: calc(200px - 100%); moves margin left of the child tag as much as the parent tag so it fully covers the page.

Comment: Hi Ramin,The above answer doesn't seem to be working for me.However when i apply margin-left: calc(-70px - 100%) to child that's when i am able to cover my screen fully.However when I resize my screen the first element goes out of screen.Tried giving parent suggestions but that isn't working as well.

Comment: I'm sorry could you please provide your code either in an online code editor or a link to repository. I'd be happy to help you

Comment: You would like to see html code with css or html would do?

Comment: please include both HTML and CSS and I'll try to fix it for you :)

Comment: Hi Ramin..HTML and css seems large enough to be copied and to be understood as it is a theme and comes from different files.Is there an alternate way you could be able to help me?

Answer (score 0):

The below code snippet should work, if I understand your question correctly. Setting the width of the child div to 100**vw** makes the div 100% of the **w**idth of the **v**iewport (window).

Also note that in order to get the child to start at the left of the viewport and not the left of the parent, I gave the child a position of absolute and a left of 0. Because the parent is not positioned, it starts the left of the child at the left of the viewport (the closest positioned ancestor).

```css
#parentDiv {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  
  background-color: orange;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

#childDiv {
  /* 100vw is 100% of the viewport width. */
  width: 100vw;
  height: 50px;
  
  background-color: lightblue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid green;
  
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

  <div id="parentDiv">
    <p>Parent</p>
    <div id="childDiv"><p>Child</p></div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Dominic..This doesn't seem to be working for me.As mentioned in the image I am able to cover the right side of screen by giving width:100vw but i am struggling to get full screen image starting from left of screen to right extreme of screen.

Comment: Giving your child a position:absolute; left:0; will solve your problem if your parent is position:static; If your parent isn't/can't be static, check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6867244/7300063.

Answer (score 0):

use Viewport Sizes so it will cover the whole page  (vw and vh)

```css
  #first {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background:gray; 
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

}
#second{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background:blue;
    position:absolute;
    
}
```

```html
   <div id="first">
  <div id="second">
  something
  </div>
</div>
```