# How to make this menu come up front without using position fixed?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a menu that opens up when you click on it. When open, the menu opens within the relative div. Because that div it's height is not that big (since its a navbar) a scrollbar appears. This is how that looks like:
[image]

I would like my menu to stick out above everything else like this:
[image]

To get this image, all I changed in css is `position: absolute` to `fixed`. This ofcourse does not work because when I scroll within the page, the menu sticks on the same spot while the navbar does not. So you would see a big gap like this:
[image]
I want my menu to stick below the "username" button like in the 2nd image.

I also tried to put my parent div on absolute. Which makes the menu behave exactly as I want it. But the issue is that my navbar buttons will go trough the username button making the website not responsive. I tried using margin in place of it but that does not make things better.
I also tried to look at things like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867244/force-position-absolute-to-be-relative-to-the-document-and-not-the-parent-con), but it is just not the right answer im looking for.

This is an example code with basicly the exact same CSS and HTML, just not in twig:

```html
<div class="navbar background-gray">
    <div class="d-flex m-nav-container">
        <p class="color-red my-auto fs-25 mr-10 mr-2-ipad-pro d-none-ipad"><a href="/">Title</a></p>
        
        <div class="d-flex wrap gap-1 grow mr-1">            
            <a class="my-auto" href="/">
                <div class="white-background-display radius-25 background-white pointer d-flex fs-14">
                    <i class="fas fa-plus fa-lg color-red my-auto mr-05 mr-05-phone"></i>
                    <p class="color-lightgray d-none-phone nowrap-text">Add button</p>
                </div>
            </a>

            <div class="white-background-display radius-25 background-white pointer d-flex fs-14 my-auto">
                <i class="far fa-chart-bar fa-lg color-red my-auto mr-05 mr-05-phone"></i>
                <p class="color-lightgray d-none-phone nowrap-text">Button 2</p>
            </div>

            <div class="white-background-display radius-25 background-white pointer d-flex fs-14 my-auto">
                <i class="fas fa-history fa-lg color-red my-auto mr-05 mr-05-phone"></i>
                <p class="color-lightgray d-none-phone nowrap-text">Button 3</p>
            </div>

            <a href="/account-beheer/toegang" class="white-background-display radius-25 background-white pointer d-flex fs-14 my-auto">
                <i class="fas fa-ban fa-lg color-red my-auto mr-05 mr-05-phone"></i>
                <p class="color-lightgray d-none-phone nowrap-text">Button 4</p>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="d-flex">
            <div class="relative">
                <div id="PageMenuOpener" class="white-background-display radius-25 d-flex mr-1 pointer" onclick="openOrCloseMenu();">
                    <i class="fas fa-user-circle color-red my-auto mr-05 mr-05-phone"></i>
                    <p class="color-lightgray fs-14 d-none-phone">Username</p>
                </div>

                <div id="PageMenu" class="pagesContainer bold background-white color-darkgray">
                    <a>
                        <div class="pageHover p-1 pointer">
                            <p>menu 1</p>
                        </div>
                    </a>

                    <a>
                        <div class="pageHover p-1 pointer">
                            <p>menu 2</p>
                        </div>
                    </a>

                    <a>
                        <div class="pageHover p-1 pointer">
                            <p>menu 3</p>
                        </div>
                    </a>

                    <a>
                        <div class="pageHover p-1 pointer">
                            <p>menu 4</p>
                        </div>
                    </a>

                    <a>
                        <div class="pageHover p-1 pointer">
                            <p>menu 5</p>
                        </div>
                    </a>

                    <a>
                        <div class="pageHover p-1 pointer">
                            <p>menu 6</p>
                        </div>
                    </a>

                    <a>
                        <div class="pageHover p-1 pointer">
                            <p>menu 7</p>
                        </div>
                    </a>

                    <a>
                        <div class="pageHover p-1 pointer">
                            <p>menu 8</p>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <a class="my-auto d-none-ipad">
                <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt color-gray fs-20"></i>
            </a>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
/* Only the basic styling is shown here. Fontawesome icons and some detail css is kept awey to keep things small. */

/* Just like bootstrap: */
/* .fs-... means font size. */
/* .m-... means margin. .mr-... means margin right. etc. */
/* .d-flex means display: flex; */

body {
    margin: 0px;
}

.d-flex {
    display: flex;
}

.wrap {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.grow {
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.gap-1 {
    gap: 1rem;
}

.navbar {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 9999;
    min-height: 100px;
}

.m-nav-container {
    margin: 2rem 2rem 3rem 2rem;
}

.relative {
    position: relative;
}

.pagesContainer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    max-height: 75vh;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 1;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: .5rem 0rem;
    right: 1rem;
    margin-top: .25rem;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.pageHover:hover {
    background-color: rgb(233, 233, 233);
}

.nowrap-text {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

/* Screens with a width of 1090 or smaller. */
@media only screen and (max-width: 1090px) {
    .m-nav-container {
        margin: 2rem 14rem 2rem 2rem;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .m-nav-container {
        margin: 2rem 9rem 2rem 2rem;
    }
}

/* Phone portrait mode AKA every screen with a width of or below 600. */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .navbar {
        min-height: 70px;
    }

    .m-nav-container {
        margin: 1rem 5rem 1rem 1rem;
    }

    .mr-05-phone {
        margin-right: 0rem;
    }

    .logout-container {
        margin-right: 0rem;
    }

    .wrap-phone {
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .nav-items-phone {
        width: 65%;
    }

    .nowrap-text-phone {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share your website cod if possible, and why don't you set header also fix it's more accessible.

Comment: @Nikkkshit the code above is my website code. Just the essentials of it. You should be able to reproduce. I dont want by navbar fixed because of design choice.

Comment: Unfortunately, It does not reproduce the same header.

Comment: @Nikkkshit Did a slight edit and now you can copy paste html into html file and css into css file. Link each other and ur done. Just change `.pagesContainer` its absolute to relative and you see the effect the image has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the issue was and its actually quite simple. I had a parent div with `position: relative` just removing that worked. I had tried this before but after a slight rebuild my menu responded perfectly. This is my code now:

HTML:

```html
<div class="navbar background-gray">
    <div class="d-flex m-nav-container">
        <p class="color-red my-auto fs-25 mr-10 mr-2-ipad-pro d-none-ipad"><a href="/">title</a></p>
        
        <div class="d-flex wrap gap-1 grow mr-1">
            <a class="my-auto" href="/">
                <div class="white-background-display radius-25 background-white pointer d-flex fs-14">
                    <i class="fas fa-plus fa-lg color-red my-auto mr-05 mr-05-phone"></i>
                    <p class="color-lightgray d-none-phone nowrap-text">button 1</p>
                </div>
            </a>

            <div class="white-background-display radius-25 background-white pointer d-flex fs-14 my-auto" onclick="showModal('UsersOverviewHours')">
                <i class="far fa-chart-bar fa-lg color-red my-auto mr-05 mr-05-phone"></i>
                <p class="color-lightgray d-none-phone nowrap-text">button 2</p>
            </div>

            <div class="white-background-display radius-25 background-white pointer d-flex fs-14 my-auto" onclick="showModal('SelectPeriod')">
                <i class="fas fa-history fa-lg color-red my-auto mr-05 mr-05-phone"></i>
                <p class="color-lightgray d-none-phone nowrap-text">button 3</p>
            </div>

            <a href="/" class="white-background-display radius-25 background-white pointer d-flex fs-14 my-auto">
                <i class="fas fa-ban fa-lg color-red my-auto mr-05 mr-05-phone"></i>
                <p class="color-lightgray d-none-phone nowrap-text">button 4</p>
            </a>
        </div>
        
        <div class="d-flex">
            <!-- Removed the "relative" class which made things work. -->
            <div>
                <div id="PageMenuOpener" class="white-background-display radius-25 d-flex mr-1 pointer" onclick="openOrCloseMenu();">
                    <i class="fas fa-user-circle color-red my-auto mr-05 mr-05-phone"></i>
                    <p class="color-lightgray fs-14 d-none-phone">username</p>
                </div>

                <div id="PageMenu" class="pagesContainer bold background-white color-darkgray">
                    <a>
                        <div class="pageHover p-1 pointer">
                            <p>menu 1</p>
                        </div>
                    </a>

                    <a>
                        <div class="pageHover p-1 pointer">
                            <p>menu 2</p>
                        </div>
                    </a>

                    <a>
                        <div class="pageHover p-1 pointer">
                            <p>menu 3</p>
                        </div>
                    </a>

                    <a>
                        <div class="pageHover p-1 pointer">
                            <p>menu 4</p>
                        </div>
                    </a>

                    <a>
                        <div class="pageHover p-1 pointer">
                            <p>menu 5</p>
                        </div>
                    </a>

                    <a>
                        <div class="pageHover p-1 pointer">
                            <p>menu 6</p>
                        </div>
                    </a>

                    <a>
                        <div class="pageHover p-1 pointer">
                            <p>menu 7</p>
                        </div>
                    </a>

                    <a>
                        <div class="pageHover p-1 pointer">
                            <p>menu 8</p>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <a class="my-auto d-none-ipad">
                <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt color-gray fs-20"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
body {
    margin: 0rem;
}

.background-gray {
    background-color: rgb(189, 189, 189);
}

.background-white {
    background-color: white;
}

.d-flex {
    display: flex;
}

.wrap {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.gap {
    gap: 1rem;
}

.grow {
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.navbar {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 9999;
    min-height: 100px;
}

.m-nav-container {
    margin: 2rem 2rem 3rem 2rem;
}

.mr-10 {
    margin-right: 10rem;
}

.fs-25 {
    font-size: 25px;
}

.fs-20 {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.pagesContainer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    max-height: 75vh;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 1;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: .5rem 0rem;
    right: 4rem;
    margin-top: .25rem;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.pageHover:hover {
    background-color: rgb(233, 233, 233);
}

.clocked-in-button {
    height: 16px;
    background-color: white;
    margin-right: 1rem;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    border-radius: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.nowrap-text {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.mt-logout-icon {
    margin-top: 5.5px;
}

/* Ipad pro landscape mode AKA every screen with a width of or below 1024. */
@media only screen and (max-width: 1366px) {
    .mr-2-ipad-pro {
        margin-right: 2rem;
    }
}

/* Phone portrait mode AKA every screen with a width of or below 600. */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .navbar {
        min-height: 70px;
    }

    .m-nav-container {
        margin: 1rem 1rem 1rem 1rem;
    }

    .mr-05-phone {
        margin-right: 0rem;
    }

    .nowrap-text-phone {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
}
```